# Use Java Sockets to connect a DNS server and download a picture from internet

Tags: java, sockets, dns, pdu

I'm making a project in java using Sockets that consist in connect a DNS server having a url and receive the IP, but that IP will be from a host where the picture is hosted in internet (doesn't matter what picture) and the last step is to get that image and save it in a text file, in binary. The thing here is that I need to show the PDU that I send to the DNS server and the answer. Also need the PDU from the others HTTP querys to download the picture. 
I'm quite confused, I have never use Sockets before, if anyone can show me how to do or give me where find information about I'll be very thankful. Thanks.

Comment: Pictures don't have IP addresses. The DNS lookup in Java is automatic. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I refer to the IP where the picture is hosted. What I need is to make the DNS lookup manually.

Comment: Then you need to acquaint yourself with Java `DatagramSockets` and `DatagramPackets` and the DNS RFC. Too broad to answer here.